# Core error when calling remove_menu_page

Tags: errors, warnings, wp-error

During developent, my error log keeps getting polluted by errors from core WP. Since they are coming from core WP, I cannot fix them(technically I can, but I don't think that's a good idea). I wanted to know if there is any way to stop these errors from appearing in the error log (but still show my own errors)

This is the error I'm getting: `PHP Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1780`

Thank you.

**Update:**

Turns out it was my own plugin that was causing the warning. But I don't understand why it is causing the warning. I'm using standard WP functions. Here is the code that is causing the warning:

```
//Remove unneeded menu items from admin
function remove_menu_items(){

/**
 * Top-level menus to remove
 */
$to_remove = [
    "separator1",
    "separator2",
    //"index.php",
    "edit.php",
    "edit.php?post_type=page",
    "edit-comments.php",
    "themes.php",
    "tools.php",
    //"options-general.php",
    "woocommerce",
    "woocommerce-marketing",
    "wc-admin&path=/analytics/overview",
    //"plugins.php"

];

/*
    Submenus to remove. Format:
    [
        "menu1_slug" => [
            "submenu1_slug",
            "submenu2_slug
        ],
        "menu2_slug => [
            "submenu1_slug",
            "submenu2_slug"
        ]
    ]

    Some of the WooCommerce submenus don't get removed even if they're added to this list.
    The workaround is to hide these items with CSS in the customCSS() function
*/
$submenus_to_remove = [
    "edit.php?post_type=product" => [
        "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_tag&post_type=product",
        "product_attributes",
        "product-reviews"
    ],
    "index.php" => [
        "update-core.php"
    ],
    "options-general.php" => [
        "options-general.php",
        "options-writing.php",
        "options-reading.php",
        "options-discussion.php",
        "options-media.php",
        "options-permalink.php",
        "options-privacy.php"

    ]
];



foreach($to_remove as $item){
    remove_menu_page($item);
}

foreach($submenus_to_remove as $parent_slug => $parent){
    foreach($parent as $submenu_item){
        remove_submenu_page($parent_slug, $submenu_item);
    }
}

}
add_action( 'admin_init', "remove_menu_items" );
```

Comment: Like what? There aren't any normally core WP errors.

Comment: It might be worth investigating them and trying to fix them at least. Some might actually be errors reportable back to WordPress; others might be errors raised by core but ultimately triggered by your code.

Comment: they're more likely to be coming from your own code but because there are no stack traces the location causing them isn't visible in your error log. If you had examples it would be clearer how to help you and fix your code. A stock WP install should generate zero messages in the PHP error log

Comment: The errors are not coming from WordPress core. A normal WordPress install on a properly configured server will not fill up the error log. It shouldn't display any errors at all. However, because themes and plugins run inside WordPress most non-syntax errors will 'bubble up' and appear to be thrown by a core WordPress function. This doesn't mean WordPress caused the error. It usually means a problem in a theme or plugin. You will need to look at a full stack trace of the errors to find the ultimate cause. Enabling WP_DEBUG can help with this.

Comment: @Rup thanks for your responses. This is the error in the log: `PHP Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1780` . It keeps spamming my error logs.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try installing a fresh WP instance and see if the error is there

Comment: Thanks. If you've got any more these are best edited into the question rather than posted as comments.

Comment: @HiMyNameIs The line throwing the error is https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1780. This means that a theme or plugin is modifying the `global $menu` variable improperly. Use the standard debugging steps of deactivating themes and plugins until the error goes away to find the source

Comment: and if you can get a stack trace that would be useful too, to see where exactly remove_menu_item is being called from.

Comment: I'd also suggest installing query monitor, it may provide more information such as stack traces that tell you exactly which function is causing the problem. It could be that a plugin decided to use a global variable and chose to also use `$menu` without testing for clashes/interference

Comment: Turns out it was my own plugin causing the warning. But I'm not sure why it is causing a warning, as I'm using standard WP functions. You can see the code that is causing the warning in my question's update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error line comes from the following in [`wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2-branch/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1780):

```
function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
    global $menu;

    foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
        if ( $menu_slug === $item[2] ) {
            unset( $menu[ $i ] );
            return $item;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The `global $menu` does not actually get populated until the [`wp-admin/menu-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2-branch/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L27) is included. See [`admin.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2-branch/wp-admin/admin.php#L239) -> [`admin-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2-branch/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L258) as well. Any hook prior to that include is going to throw a similar error.

The `admin_init` hook is too early to access the `global $menu`. You should be using the [`admin_menu` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/) instead.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: Using `admin_menu` is the correct action, but not for the reason mentioned.

`admin_init` runs in `/wp-admin/admin.php`, `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and `/wp-admin/admin-post.php`. 
When running in the admin-ajax.php, the `global $menu` is not available. This is why the initial code works (when it runs through `admin.php`), but also create warnings (when the hook runs through `admin-ajax.php`). As a matter of fact, `admin_menu` runs **before** `admin_init` when loading the dashboard. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Thank you @LyK, that now fully explains the behaviour I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm creating another answer to include info from [@Lyk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47375/lyk) (thank you)*

### Wrong hook

You need to use a different hook: `admin_menu` instead of `admin_init`.

```php
add_action( 'admin_menu', "remove_menu_items" );
```

### because...

As [@Lyk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47375/lyk) explains:

> `admin_init` runs [not only] in `/wp-admin/admin.php`, [but also in] `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and `/wp-admin/admin-post.php`.

> When running in the admin-ajax.php, the `global $menu` is not available. This is why the initial code works (when it runs through `admin.php`), but also create warnings (when the hook runs through `admin-ajax.php`).

Original comment here: [Core error when calling remove_menu_page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/414626/core-error-when-calling-remove-menu-page/#comment-610172)